# Can I cast a half implemented mock to a type with flowtype?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, flowtype

I'm using flowtype to annotate types in my JavaScript. In my tests I would also like to take advantage of flowtype.

I am testing that a function is given an argument that is an object with another function and that this other function is called the right number of times with the expected argument.

Example code:

```
function foo(obj: Bar) {
   obj.bar('bar');
}
```

Example test:

```
test('foo gets bar', t => {
    const mockBar: Bar = {
       bar: sinon.stub(),
    };
    foo(mockBar);
    t.true(mockBar.bar.calledWith('bar'));
});
```

Now `Bar` is a really complicated type with lots of properties and such and is not easy to mock fully and here I only want to test that `'bar'` is given. Flowtype has none of this and errors out on saying that my `mockBar` is not really `Bar` and I'm not sure what to do at this point other than to not use flowtype in testing or mock out `Bar` completely somehow which would be a lot of work for a little test.

Can I simply somehow force cast the mock to be Bar in a way flowtype will be happy with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, I might have found a better solution.

```
// Upcast mockBar to any then downcast any to Bar.
// Unsafe downcasting from any is allowed: OK
((mockBar: any): Bar);
```

The above expression will have type of `Bar`.

Source: https://flowtype.org/blog/2015/02/18/Typecasts.html

The benefit of this approach is that only typecasting errors are ignored. Errors from e.g. non-existing variables would still be detected.

Comment: This worked thank you, I had to pass it in like this: `foo(((mockBar: any): Bar));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flow's error suppression comments to ignore the error. You'll need to define the comment pattern in `.flowconfig`.

From the [docs](https://flowtype.org/docs/advanced-configuration.html):

`suppress_comment` (regex): defines a magical comment that suppresses any Flow errors on the following line. For example:

`suppress_comment= \\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$FlowFixMe`

will match a comment like this:

```
// $FlowFixMe: suppressing this error until we can refactor
var x : string = 123;
```

Comment: If I did this I might as well just not use flow from testing. I was really hoping for a way to cast.

Comment: @BjornTipling You can cast any variable to any type like this: `(myVar: Type)`. However, since in your example you're defining a new variable, you don't need to cast – you can just specify the type you want. Both casting and what you want will fail to typecheck in your case because you're not implementing the required fields. So if you want that to work, you need to turn off typechecking for that one cast or declaration. Any language feature that would allow you do this would effectively be suppressing type system error. Note that error suppression comment only silences errors on one line.